# List of integers, raising each element to a power

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Trying perform function y=x**E%N on numbers in list (72, 36, 72, 25, 72, 28,.....) Note that the empty elements are important to keep.

```
mylist = [[72, 36], ' ', [72, 25], [72, 28], [72, 38], ' ', [72, 28]]
E = 3233
N = 17

for i in mylist:
    if i != ' ':
        i[0] = i[0]**E%N
        i[1] = i[1]**E%N
```

When I try this I get the following error:

TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: "Doesn't work" how? And your code has pretty bad antipatterns. And the problem is probably that you're rebinding the name `J` instead of mutating your original list elements.

Comment: Fixed the colons, thanks. What do you mean by antipatterns? Sorry, relatively new to python, unfamiliar with the jargon. Are you saying I should individually change the elements?

Comment: 1. Don't call a variable `list` because that shadows the built-in type `list`. 2. Instead of looping over indices, you should loop over the list itself: `for J in lst: ...`. 3. When you do `J = J**E%N` then (a) you're doing this with a list; not what you want to do and (b) you're rebinding the name `J` instead of mutating the original list. Read up on what mutable containers are and what rebinding is. My suggestion: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html . 4. read [ask] and [mcve], 5. your separator being an empty string looks a bit weird/counter-intuitive.

Comment: Ahh thanks I realize what you are saying about rebinding, will try something else.

Comment: `lst_new = [([k**E%N for k in elem] if elem!=' ' else elem) for elem in lst]` or something similar is probably what you need in a condensed way

Comment: And watch out for precedence: `k**E%N` is the same as `(k**E)%N`, it might or might not be what you mean.

Comment: Please, what is the desired output?

Comment: Your recent edit has been rolled back. There is no reason to edit "solved" into your question, and you shouldn't remove relevant information. If one of the answers solve your problem, mark it as accepted using the tick mark on the left side of the answer. If they didn't solve it but you solved it yourself, consider adding an answer of your own. Accepting an answer indicates that it is "solved".

Answer (score 1):

You should try to follow common Python idioms.

1) Don't name your data `list`, you're overriding a Python built-in

2) If you're doing `for i in range(len(l)):` you're doing it wrong. Loop over the iterable itself.

3) If possible, try to keep similar types in a list.

Here's an untested example doing what I think you're trying to do:

```
data = [[72, 36], [], [72, 25], [72, 28], [72, 38], [], [72, 28]]  # replaced empty strings with empty lists, maintain type similarity 
E = 3233
N = 17

for pair in data:  # loop over list itself, not range(len(list))
    if pair:  # pair is Truthy if the element is NOT an empty list
        pair[0] = pair[0]**(E%N) 
        pair[1] = pair[1]**(E%N)
```

**EDIT**: If you absolutely must keep the spaces in your original data list:

```
data = [[72, 36], ' ', [72, 25], [72, 28], [72, 38], ' ', [72, 28]]
E = 3233
N = 17

for pair in data:  # loop over list itself, not range(len(list))
    if pair != ' ':
        pair[0] = pair[0]**(E%N) 
        pair[1] = pair[1]**(E%N)
```

Comment: if pair is True even for ' ' also why not iterating on each element instead of doing pair[0]... pair[1]... also you modified this initial list format, the OP said that the ' ' have to be kept.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with OPs code, so I suggest an alternative approach -- including not mixing types in a list. And of course iterating over each element in the sublists is possible, but this is more readable if each sublist is limited to length 2.

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up with this code, assuming that you want to perform in-place computation:

```
data = [[72, 36], ' ', [72, 25], [72, 28], [72, 38], ' ', [72, 28]]
E = 3233
N = 17

for sublist in data:
    if not isinstance(sublist, list):
        continue
    for idx, subitem in enumerate(sublist):
        item[idx] = pow(subitem, E, N)

print data
```

Output:

```
[[4, 2], ' ', [4, 8], [4, 11], [4, 4], ' ', [4, 11]]
```

Comment: I assumed he wanted `pow(subitem, e, n)` rather than what you have.

Comment: why so many downvotes? I updated with pow, but not sure he wanted pow, also what's wrong with the rest?

Comment: I didn't down vote, your code actually matched his but I doubted he meant to have (E % N).